# How to call a JavaScript function sequentially in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization

I want to pass each item into a function that take times.
But seems that the JS function is asynchronized.
How can I call the function sequentially ? (Pass next item to function after the previous done)

```
function main() {
    for (var i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        doSomething(myArray[i]);
    }
}

function doSomething(item) {
    // do something take time
}
```

My solution is call the function recusively.
But I want to know is there a different way to solve this issue ? Thanks.

```
function main() {
    doSomething(myArray, 0);
}

function doSomething(item, i) {
    // do something take time
    doSomething(myArray, i + 1);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, for-cycles and function calls in javascript are synchronous, so it must be something else that's making the function async. Maybe it's something inside the function itself.

Comment: Sorry for not mention that, my code is running on a node.js server. Is that why the function is async ?

Comment: `myArray.forEach(doSomething)` comes to mind.

Comment: Functions don't become async just because they're on node.js. What does your function actually do? Asynchronous functions usually have a callback facility or return a promise, so you can use that to coordinate the subsequent call.

Comment: Hi @nnnnnn, the function do something like http post request, and i have a callback function. My solution is put the doSomething(myArray, i + 1); inside the callback function.

Comment: That's a reasonably normal way to do it. (Note that it isn't actually a truly recursive call, because `doSomething()` isn't calling itself, it is completing and then *later* the callback is called and from there you call `doSomething()` again - kind of pseudo-recursive.)

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript, as of 2020, the for-loop is async/await aware. You can return a promise and then `await` that promise inside of the for loop. This causes the loop to execute in a series, even for long running operations.

```
function randomSleep(ms, seed=10) {
    ms = ms * Math.random() * seed;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>setTimeout(resolve, ms));
} 
async function doSomething(idx) {
  // long running operations
  const outcome = await randomSleep(500);
  return idx;
}   
const arrItems = ['a','b','c','d'];
for(let i=0,len=arrItems.length;i<len;i++) {
  const result = await doSomething(i);
  console.log("result is", result)
}
```

Read more about async await in for loops and forEach loops here https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass next item to function after the previous done, you can try to use promise, just like this

```
var Q = require('q'); 
var promise;
main();
function main() {
     promise = doSomethingPromise(0)
    for (var i = 1; i < 10 ; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            promise = promise.then(function (res) {
                return doSomethingPromise(res + ' ' + i)
            });
        })(i)

    }
}

function doSomethingPromise (item) {
   var d = Q.defer();
      d.resolve(doSomething(item));
   return d.promise;
}

function doSomething(item) {
    // do something take time
    console.log('doSomething', item);
    return item;
}
```

it can make you function to be called by order.

Comment: Hi chenkehxx, I've tried your answer. But looks item[1] to item[item.length-1] are stuck in line Q.defer().

Comment: can I see your all code?, I don't run my code neither. it is just pseudocode.

Comment: HI chenkenhxx, my code is just like what you wrote here.

Comment: @Aaron, I have update my code, you can try it again.

Comment: Hi chenkehxx, I've tried your modified answer, but the log shows that only the first item is run in the doSomething function.

Comment: Finally, I create a function array in for loop and use **async.series** to do what I want.